# How to add custom page.html.twig for views page?

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have a view page with url and machine id search

I need to add a custom page.html.twig for that specific view page so that it does not affect the rest pages.

How can I implement it?

I tried adding page--search.html.twig but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sticking on page URL, I've done this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter().
 */
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  $parameters = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters()->all();
  if (isset($parameters['view_id']) && isset($parameters['display_id'])) {
    ['view_id' => $view_id, 'display_id' => $display_id] = $parameters;
    $suggestions[] = 'page__view__' . $view_id;
    $suggestions[] = 'page__view__' . $view_id . '__' . $display_id;
  }
}
```

Then you can simply use page--view--search.html.twig

Answer (score 1):

page--[url of your view].html.twig

Put the file in `drupal/themes/YourTheme/templates` folder

Remember to flush/clear the cache to see the changes.